# Unable to deploy Django app to Heroku with waitress

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

I tried a few weeks ago to host a Django app to Heroku, but when I try opening my app, I get an `Application Error`. I tried many alternatives as well but nothing seems to work for me, as it's the same error again. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Please do let me know if I need to include any other files.
`Procfile`:

```
web: waitress-serve --listen=*:5000 Cakewala_Attendance.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
heroku ps:scale web=1
python manage.py migrate
```

`.gitignore`:

```
# Created by https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/visualstudiocode,django
# Edit at https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore?templates=visualstudiocode,django

### Django ###
*.log
*.pot
*.pyc
__pycache__/
local_settings.py
db.sqlite3
db.sqlite3-journal
media

# If your build process includes running collectstatic, then you probably don't need or want to include staticfiles/
# in your Git repository. Update and uncomment the following line accordingly.
# <django-project-name>/staticfiles/

### Django.Python Stack ###
# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
*.py[cod]
*$py.class

# C extensions
*.so

# Distribution / packaging
.Python
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
downloads/
eggs/
.eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
wheels/
share/python-wheels/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg
MANIFEST

# PyInstaller
#  Usually these files are written by a python script from a template
#  before PyInstaller builds the exe, so as to inject date/other infos into it.
*.manifest
*.spec

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
htmlcov/
.tox/
.nox/
.coverage
.coverage.*
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml
*.cover
*.py,cover
.hypothesis/
.pytest_cache/
cover/

# Translations
*.mo

# Django stuff:

# Flask stuff:
instance/
.webassets-cache

# Scrapy stuff:
.scrapy

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/

# PyBuilder
.pybuilder/
target/

# Jupyter Notebook
.ipynb_checkpoints

# IPython
profile_default/
ipython_config.py

# pyenv
#   For a library or package, you might want to ignore these files since the code is
#   intended to run in multiple environments; otherwise, check them in:
# .python-version

# pipenv
#   According to pypa/pipenv#598, it is recommended to include Pipfile.lock in version control.
#   However, in case of collaboration, if having platform-specific dependencies or dependencies
#   having no cross-platform support, pipenv may install dependencies that don't work, or not
#   install all needed dependencies.
#Pipfile.lock

# poetry
#   Similar to Pipfile.lock, it is generally recommended to include poetry.lock in version control.
#   This is especially recommended for binary packages to ensure reproducibility, and is more
#   commonly ignored for libraries.
#   https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#commit-your-poetrylock-file-to-version-control
#poetry.lock

# pdm
#   Similar to Pipfile.lock, it is generally recommended to include pdm.lock in version control.
#pdm.lock
#   pdm stores project-wide configurations in .pdm.toml, but it is recommended to not include it
#   in version control.
#   https://pdm.fming.dev/#use-with-ide
.pdm.toml

# PEP 582; used by e.g. github.com/David-OConnor/pyflow and github.com/pdm-project/pdm
__pypackages__/

# Celery stuff
celerybeat-schedule
celerybeat.pid

# SageMath parsed files
*.sage.py

# Environments
.env
.venv
env/
venv/
ENV/
env.bak/
venv.bak/

# Spyder project settings
.spyderproject
.spyproject

# Rope project settings
.ropeproject

# mkdocs documentation
/site

# mypy
.mypy_cache/
.dmypy.json
dmypy.json

# Pyre type checker
.pyre/

# pytype static type analyzer
.pytype/

# Cython debug symbols
cython_debug/

# PyCharm
#  JetBrains specific template is maintained in a separate JetBrains.gitignore that can
#  be found at https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/Global/JetBrains.gitignore
#  and can be added to the global gitignore or merged into this file.  For a more nuclear
#  option (not recommended) you can uncomment the following to ignore the entire idea folder.
#.idea/

### VisualStudioCode ###
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
!.vscode/*.code-snippets

# Local History for Visual Studio Code
.history/

# Built Visual Studio Code Extensions
*.vsix

### VisualStudioCode Patch ###
# Ignore all local history of files
.history
.ionide

# Support for Project snippet scope
.vscode/*.code-snippets

# Ignore code-workspaces
*.code-workspace

# End of https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/visualstudiocode,django
```

`Heroku Logs`:

```
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664062+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664062+00:00 app[web.1]: --unix-socket=PATH
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664062+00:00 app[web.1]: Path of Unix socket. If a socket path is specified, a Unix domain
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664062+00:00 app[web.1]: socket is made instead of the usual inet domain socket.  
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664063+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664063+00:00 app[web.1]: Not available on Windows.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664063+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664063+00:00 app[web.1]: --unix-socket-perms=PERMS
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664063+00:00 app[web.1]: Octal permissions to use for the Unix domain socket, default is
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664063+00:00 app[web.1]: '600'.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664063+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664064+00:00 app[web.1]: --url-scheme=STR
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664064+00:00 app[web.1]: Default wsgi.url_scheme value, default is 'http'.        
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664064+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664064+00:00 app[web.1]: --url-prefix=STR
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664064+00:00 app[web.1]: The ``SCRIPT_NAME`` WSGI environment value.  Setting this to anything
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664064+00:00 app[web.1]: except the empty string will cause the WSGI ``SCRIPT_NAME`` value to be
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664064+00:00 app[web.1]: the value passed minus any trailing slashes you add, and 
it will cause
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664065+00:00 app[web.1]: the ``PATH_INFO`` of any request which is prefixed with this value to
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664065+00:00 app[web.1]: be stripped of the prefix.  Default is the empty string. 
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664065+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664065+00:00 app[web.1]: --ident=STR
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664065+00:00 app[web.1]: Server identity used in the 'Server' header in responses. Default
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664065+00:00 app[web.1]: is 'waitress'.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664065+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664065+00:00 app[web.1]: Tuning options:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664066+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664066+00:00 app[web.1]: --threads=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664066+00:00 app[web.1]: Number of threads used to process application logic, default is 4.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664066+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664066+00:00 app[web.1]: --backlog=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664066+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection backlog for the server. Default is 1024.      
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664067+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664067+00:00 app[web.1]: --recv-bytes=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664074+00:00 app[web.1]: Number of bytes to request when calling socket.recv(). Default is
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664074+00:00 app[web.1]: 8192.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664074+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664075+00:00 app[web.1]: --send-bytes=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664075+00:00 app[web.1]: Number of bytes to send to socket.send(). Default is 18000.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664075+00:00 app[web.1]: Multiples of 9000 should avoid partly-filled TCP packets.2022-07-12T16:50:00.664076+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664076+00:00 app[web.1]: --outbuf-overflow=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664076+00:00 app[web.1]: A temporary file should be created if the pending output 
is larger
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664076+00:00 app[web.1]: than this. Default is 1048576 (1MB).
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664076+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664076+00:00 app[web.1]: --outbuf-high-watermark=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664077+00:00 app[web.1]: The app_iter will pause when pending output is larger than this value
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664077+00:00 app[web.1]: and will resume once enough data is written to the socket to fall below
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664077+00:00 app[web.1]: this threshold. Default is 16777216 (16MB).
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664077+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664077+00:00 app[web.1]: --inbuf-overflow=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664077+00:00 app[web.1]: A temporary file should be created if the pending input is larger
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664077+00:00 app[web.1]: than this. Default is 524288 (512KB).
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664078+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664078+00:00 app[web.1]: --connection-limit=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664078+00:00 app[web.1]: Stop creating new channels if too many are already active.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664078+00:00 app[web.1]: Default is 100.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664078+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664078+00:00 app[web.1]: --cleanup-interval=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664078+00:00 app[web.1]: Minimum seconds between cleaning up inactive channels. Default
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664078+00:00 app[web.1]: is 30. See '--channel-timeout'.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664079+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664079+00:00 app[web.1]: --channel-timeout=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664079+00:00 app[web.1]: Maximum number of seconds to leave inactive connections open.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664079+00:00 app[web.1]: Default is 120. 'Inactive' is defined as 'has received no data
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664079+00:00 app[web.1]: from the client and has sent no data to the client'.     
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664079+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664080+00:00 app[web.1]: --[no-]log-socket-errors
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664080+00:00 app[web.1]: Toggle whether premature client disconnect tracebacks ought to be
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664080+00:00 app[web.1]: logged. On by default.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664080+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664080+00:00 app[web.1]: --max-request-header-size=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664080+00:00 app[web.1]: Maximum size of all request headers combined. Default is 
262144
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664080+00:00 app[web.1]: (256KB).
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664081+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664081+00:00 app[web.1]: --max-request-body-size=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664083+00:00 app[web.1]: Maximum size of request body. Default is 1073741824 (1GB).
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664084+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664084+00:00 app[web.1]: --[no-]expose-tracebacks
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664084+00:00 app[web.1]: Toggle whether to expose tracebacks of unhandled exceptions to the
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664084+00:00 app[web.1]: client. Off by default.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664084+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664084+00:00 app[web.1]: --asyncore-loop-timeout=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664085+00:00 app[web.1]: The timeout value in seconds passed to asyncore.loop(). Default is 1.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664085+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664085+00:00 app[web.1]: --asyncore-use-poll
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664085+00:00 app[web.1]: The use_poll argument passed to ``asyncore.loop()``. Helps overcome
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664085+00:00 app[web.1]: open file descriptors limit. Default is False.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664085+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664086+00:00 app[web.1]: --channel-request-lookahead=INT
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664086+00:00 app[web.1]: Allows channels to stay readable and buffer more requests up to the
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664086+00:00 app[web.1]: given maximum even if a request is already being processed. This allows
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664086+00:00 app[web.1]: detecting if a client closed the connection while its request is being
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664086+00:00 app[web.1]: processed. Default is 0.
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664086+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.664086+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-07-12T16:50:00.801662+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-12T16:50:00.865460+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-12T16:50:31.248220+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=cakewala-attendance.herokuapp.com request_id=e53f0c42-2205-4e90-b8c0-4477ccf5dd0d fwd="106.51.142.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
2022-07-12T16:50:31.954123+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=cakewala-attendance.herokuapp.com request_id=a86239ab-8ecd-4d19-bf9d-b574884363b2 
fwd="106.51.142.72" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
```

Comment: This won't have anything to do with Git - Git is just *relaying* error messages for Heroku here. Look at your heroku logs more closely: what you've posted here appears to just be the last few (tens of) lines, while whatever the actual error is, is probably in the *first* few lines.

Comment: I don't understand completely, but as for the last sentence, I copy pasted the whole `heroku logs --tail` output

Comment: I don't actually use Heroku, but `--tail` obviously means "show the last however-many lines". You're going to need more lines, as something has dumped a "how to use this command" series of lines and then exited, probably *after* saying something like "error: --foo option unrecognized". This option is probably for some earlier or later version, or a typo. Unfortunately, the usage dump has thereby wiped out the useful clues, at least with `--tail`.

Comment: Oh, what can I do now?

Comment: As I don't actually use Heroku, I don't know. You'll need some Heroku and/or domain (Django?) expert here.